# How to insert html not from database and not using the iframe?

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I wish basically to store my pages or product long descriptions in txt or html files in folders, not in database.
Is there any simple and easy way to do so, instead of iframe which does not work quite well and does not even display the content in the page code so it is not indexed by search engines as it should.

I've read about web components html imports but that seem to be so much complicated and does not really satisfy my needs.

I have not found any plugin to do so, maybe there is one.

I know I wish to make wordpress flat file cms, but maybe there is some new easy way to simply insert pages from anywhere but database might be via shortcode or just an url.

Comment: Do you just want to be able to insert text into a div on existing pages?  
Are the pages you wish to insert on your server?

Comment: Take a look at the answer below as it was too long for this section

Answer (score 0):

I put it in tags, should say more clear, it is about wordpress on host. As it stores all pages and data in database and I realized bigger database is slower it works. I use caching plugin but I also wish to speed up admin panel and dynamic uncacheble content. My idea is to slim down the database as much as possible and in my woocommerce store most of the data is long description. So the best way would be to inject the long description via shortcode that would take html content from anywhere else but database. I need html, not just some text to insert. This way I would cache these product pages anyway but the database would stay way slimmer and all the dynamic content would go way faster.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use the function `file_get_contents`, which will display the contents of a file (but not parse it as PHP, which is more secure for obvious reasons).

So you could try something like this if you wanted to account for a page not found message:

```php
function example_get_content($file_url){
  if(file_exists($file_url)){
    return file_get_contents($file_url);
 }
 else{
    return 'Sorry, this page could not be found'
 }
}
```

And then in your template use

```php
echo example_get_content('http://example.com/my_text_file.txt');
```

Comment: If I use it in template it will not be unique content for each page.

Comment: You could do something like `example_get_content('http://example.com/content-'.get_the_id().'.txt');` then, and save each post's content as content-1.txt etc?

Comment: Your idea is not actually gonna let me insert exact txt wherever I need. I think this might work. Maybe I will use insert php plugin and than use echo example_get_content('http://example.com/my_text_file.txt');  on each page I need with above code for functions.php. I will try it probably. Let you know if it works.

Comment: It does not work. When I add the function into the functions.php the wordpress site stops working, even admin panel, nothing works.

Comment: Ok it kind of works. I put this code in php snippet plugin loaded via shortcode: <?php
$content= file_get_contents('https://example.com/product1.txt');
echo $content;
?> There is yet another problem. As I don't want to make a php shortcode and paste it to the descrption for each page or product description. Is there a way to allow php in the description without shortcodes? Just on the very place I want to use it, that would safe a lot of time for me. There was a plugin that was allowing it: insert php but it has a different name now and it only uses shortcodes.

Comment: Ok it works! Great! We just made a wordpress partly flat file cms the way I wanted xD Insert php plugin version 1.3 is still available to download and use and it works perfetcly. That's lovely. Thanks for help!